# Bootstrap or css - is there a way to hide 0 value int or decimal in a table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple html table and was wondering if there was a way with css to hide 0 int and decimals?

[image]

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="1">
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
    <th>Column 4</th>
    <tr>
      <td>row1 col1</td>
      <td>row1 col2</td>
      <td>row1 col3</td>
      <td>0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row2 col1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>row2 col3</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row3 col1</td>
      <td>row3 col2</td>
      <td>row3 col3</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row4 col1</td>
      <td>row4 col2</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rodsan724/vdqL3ajg/

Comment: It doesn't seem possible via CSS currently. If rendering data from another source, you could use `Number.prototype.toLocaleString()` or `Intl.NumberFormat` methods. — See MDN doc for [Number.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) and for [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) for reference.